# Why does adding `var` stop the value from being displayed in the JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, console, var

In the JavaScript console in Chrome, if I don't use `var`, then the value assigned is displayed.

```
a = 2
// <- 2
```

If I do use `var`, then the value is not displayed.

```
var b = 3
// <- undefined
```

Why the difference?

Comment: Because the console executes the code and then displays its result. The result of a `var` statement (with or without assignment) is `undefined`. The result of `a=2` is 2, which is why you can say `c=b=a=2` to assign the same value to several variables at once.